# display:inline-block and text-indent

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I am experiencing a problem with the following code in some versions of Internet Explorer:

```
#iconautente{ 
background-image:url('/style/images/spritecommon.png'); /*icona_utente.png*/
background-position:-117px -15px;
text-indent:-9000px;
width:20px;
height:23px;
display:inline-block;
}

<a id="iconautente" href="/admin/index.php">admin</a>
```

In Firefox, IE7 and IE8 under Vista, I see background and no text, as expected. In IE6 and IE8 under XP, the whole image is indented, not text, so the image is not shown.

What should be the right behavior? Is there a workaround?

Comment: using <a ...><span>admin</span></a> and #iconautente span{text-indent:-9000px;} works, but text-indent of inline-block indent whole block, not contained text. What say the standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
* html #iconautente{text-indent:0; line-height:0; font-size:0; overflow:hidden}/*ie6 hack */

*:first-child+html #iconautente{ text-indent:0; line-height:0; font-size:0; overflow:hidden}/*ie7 hack */
```

Comment: I just realized that font-size and line-height do the trick of not showing text ... thanx

Comment: The text is still displayed in Chrome browser, in a very small font size (it looks like a trail of dots).

Comment: @HalilÖzgür This is meant as a hack for IE6/7 and may have unexpected behaviors in newer browsers. I would recommend a negative text-indent combined with overflow hidden in modern browsers, and this hack for older MSIE.

Answer (score 5):

perhaps you can try like this:

```
.blk {  display:inline-block; height:96px; width:96px; text-indent:-9999px; *text-indent:0; *font-size:0; *line-height:0; *overflow:hidden; }
```

see the Demo http://jsfiddle.net/zhiyelee/4aRZa/

Comment: As far as I'm concerned this is a bug in older versions of MSIE and it requires a hack like this to solve. Why compromise newer standards for compliance with older browsers? Text indent breaks inline (inline-block) elements with dimensions applied. You can set font size as zero in newer browsers as well with the same result (no hack needed) but text-indent is my preferred method of hiding text.

Comment: To correct myself: Font-size does not behave the same way in all modern browsers, so use text-indent when possible, and override it when using IE6 or 7. Also, for those not aware: this answer is the same as the accepted answer, but uses a selector hack that targets both IE6 and 7. I prefer this method because it's less code.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>presumably</strike> internet explorer is not supporting `display: inline-block;` in versions below 7 and only partly in 7. Why don't you use `display:block;` ?

Comment: To be precise, `inline-block` is only supported in versions below 8 if the original `display` property is `inline`.

Comment: original a tag is inline. Because with display:block; dont correctly vertical-align element, and vertical-align has no effect